# Mouse cursor appears during Games

Tags: windows-10, security, mouse, gaming, mouse-cursor

from 2 days this problem happening. during game-play(windowed or full-screen) suddenly mouse cursor appears(with a sound notification but nothing shows on the notification area) on the screen and the pointer moving  as i move my mouse. i didn't installed any software from couple of days...  just installed windows updates (1803 and other ms updates ).

note: when the cursor reaches the top of the screen it comes from bottom it like a loop or something like that... like the snake game.

should i just reinstall the windows? or i can trust on you guys ?

adding the **video clip of my problem** ... please sees this :[video clip of my problem](https://youtu.be/3CmK0bRMOp0)

this is happens in **task manager**, and this sound coming. [video2](https://youtu.be/_8x75BogkBo)

Comment: Can you check if there is a connection from the outside (ssh, rdp, etc) when that happens. Maybe it's a troll bugging you.

Comment: No, no connection from outside.

Comment: it happens 3-4 min after starting any game.

Comment: Sounds like a popup or notification steals focus of the game. Check the action center (message icon right of the clock) to see what notification was brought up and deal with that. It should make this stop.

Comment: already checked that ... its empty.   and the problem is, this problem is not fixing without closing the game .... and automatically starting 2-4min after playing the game. last time i updated tencent (PUBG mobile ) gaming buddy and installed windows flash player update  and after 6hrs this problem started.

Comment: no hope yet? this happens only during games and chrome browser.

Comment: or it is only mouse problem

Comment: finally! found the problem, it was mouse hardware problem.

Comment: Same troubles, I'm gonna try to change mouth and report about results